# Алгоритм установки соотношения значений UISlider - UIImage.alpha

Tags: c, логика, алгоритм, objective-c

Вопрос на логику. Есть стандартный UISlider, который при возрастании value должен уменьшать соответственно alpha UIImage, находящейся на этом же View.

max-min значения:

- `UISlider: 0 - 100`
- `UIImage.alpha = 1 - 0`

То есть вопрос, как я понимаю, об алгоритме, который в будет устанавливать соответствующие соотношения значений, например: 0,99 - 0,01, 0,98 - 0,02 ... и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Искомый алгоритм:

```
 image.value = 1 - (slider.value / slider.maximumValue);
```